# Excel - Use fill with gaps between rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data in consecutive cells in a column in Sheet_2. 
(In my case, they happen to be dates that are approximately a month apart,
but this is probably unimportant.) 
Something like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Start of Period |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | … | 30-Dec-2019 |
| 4 | … | 30-Jan-2020 |
| 5 | … | 2-Mar-2020 |

I want to fill in a column on Sheet_1
with references to these values on Sheet_2. 
To clarify: I want to auto-fill formulas in Sheet1 that reference Sheet2. 
Each value should be repeated three times, followed by a gap (blank cell). 
It should *look* like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{}` |  |  |  |
| 2 | Cheque A | Cheque N | Date | Inclusive |
| 3 | 11150 |  | 30-Dec-2019 | x |
| 4 |  |  | 30-Dec-2019 | x |
| 5 |  |  | 30-Dec-2019 | x |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 11150 |  | 30-Jan-2020 | x |
| 8 |  |  | 30-Jan-2020 | x |
| 9 |  |  | 30-Jan-2020 | x |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | 11150 |  | 2-Mar-2020 | x |
| 12 |  |  | 2-Mar-2020 | x |
| 13 |  |  | 2-Mar-2020 | x |
| 14 |  |  |  |  |

but it should actually be references, like this:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | … |  |  |  |
| 2 | … | … | Date | … |
| 3 | … |  | =sheet2!B3 |  |
| 4 |  |  | =sheet2!B3 |  |
| 5 |  |  | =sheet2!B3 |  |
| 6 |  |  | blank |  |
| 7 | … |  | =sheet2!B4 |  |
| 8 |  |  | =sheet2!B4 |  |
| 9 |  |  | =sheet2!B4 |  |
| 10 |  |  | blank |  |
| 11 | … |  | =sheet2!B5 |  |
| 12 |  |  | =sheet2!B5 |  |
| 13 |  |  | =sheet2!B5 |  |
| 14 |  |  | blank |  |

At present, if I reference it manually and then drag and fill,
it skips a bunch of rows.

I've tried a couple of variations of INDIRECT,
but I must be using it incorrectly as I can't get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you always want Sheet\_1 to have groups of three? If so, say so. If not, how are we supposed to know how many times to repeat each value? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: People have put effort into answering your question. Please look at the answers and provide feedback — comments, [votes and/or acceptance](/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you always want Sheet_1 to have groups of three: 
In `Sheet_1!C3`, enter

```
=INDEX(Sheet_2!B$3:B$99, INT((ROW()-ROW($C$3))/4)+1, 1)
```

replacing `99` with the last row where `Sheet_2!B` has data. 
Copy that formula into cells `C4` and `C5`. 
Leave `C6` blank.

Select cells `C3:C6` and drag/fill down.

Comment: Thank you! This was a simple formula and it worked perfectly.

Also, thank you for editing my question to be more succinct and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This formula:

```
=IF(ROUNDUP((ROW()-2)/4,0) = (ROW()-2)/4,"",INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&(ROUND(ROW()/4,0)+1)))
```

Will take dates in Sheet2 and place each one on three rows on Sheet1, followed by a blank cell before the next date repeated three times, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the answer from Scott and it worked perfectly. Being so, I did not try yours. Thank you though.